# Boost bjam doesn't put compiler version in filename

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

In the past, b2 / bjam would build libraries named like so:

> libboost_wserialization-gcc48-mt-d-1_60.so (note -gcc48-)

I've just cloned boost from git and am trying to compile with G++ 8.3.0,
but the library it generates is named:

> libboost_atomic-gcc-mt-d-x64-1_66.so (note the -gcc-)

I (and CMake) was expecting it to be named:

> libboost_atomic-gcc83-mt-d-x64-1_66.so
>   (note the -gcc83-)

To build, I did:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries="atomic" --prefix=`pwd`/install
./b2 --layout=versioned link=shared variant=debug threading=multi cflags=-fPIC cxxflags=-fPIC
```

I tried googling but haven't found anything suggesting that I've done something wrong, its my understanding that --layout=versioned should result in the compiler AND version number in the library name...

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated the submodules if any? Also specify which version are you trying to compile? As per my experience I found `1.69.0` is the highest stable version. But I downloaded the library from boost.org.

Comment: Hmm I hadn't, so I did git pull; git submodule update; and now b2 says: boost-install.jam: No such file or directory... I'll try compiling a tarball next.

Comment: Ok, the tarball did ad a version to it, but not enough... libboost_atomic-gcc8-mt-d-x64-1_70.so   note its gcc8 not gcc83 ... argh

Comment: So you are now compiling it with tarball?

Comment: Yes. tar xfv boost_1_70_0.tar.bz2 ; cd boost_1_70_0/ ; ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries="atomic" ; ./b2 --layout=versioned link=shared variant=debug threading=multi cflags=-fPIC cxxflags=-fPIC ; ls -l stage/lib  === libboost_atomic-gcc8-mt-d-x64-1_70.so

Comment: The b2 command can be simplified to just  ./b2 --layout=versioned , its the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the mailing list:

```
Possibly, it's related to the change in GCC 5+ versioning.
This was accommodated in Boost.Build in October 2018
https://github.com/boostorg/build/pull/349
that is, in Boost 1.69
(boostorg/build should use milestones for issues, IMO)


BTW, there are also CMake's issues in FindCMake.cmake
related to the compiler  and architecture tag. So, you may have to
specify  Boost_COMPILER and Boost_ARCHITECTURE hints
in order to help FindBoost.cmake recognise versioned names.
```

https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2019/04/246127.php

Tip on a workaround:
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2018-October/068459.html
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17701